# Input parameter in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, input

How do I pass an input parameter to an XSLT stylesheet? I'm using xsltproc, and I'd like to use `--stringparam <param> <value>` as argument, but I don't know how to access the parameter inside the XSLT. Can someone give an example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one I am using. The default value part is optional. You must have a

```
  <xsl:param name="yourParamname"/>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <!-- default value -->
<xsl:variable name="defaultDeploymentMode">
    <xsl:text>test</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:param name="deploymentMode" select="$defaultDeploymentMode"></xsl:param>



<xsl:template match="/">
    <data><xsl:value-of select="$deploymentMode"/>
           </data>
     </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You could also specify the default value directly in the select: `<xsl:param name="deploymentMode" select="'test'"/>`

Answer (score 7):

> How to give input parameter to an xslt file?

**In XSLT any** *global* **parameter** (`xsl:param` that is a child of the top element of the XSLT stylesheet) **can have its value specified externally, by the initiator of the transformation**.

The way this setting of external parameters is done is implementation dependent and differs from one XSLT processor to another -- read the documentation of the specific XSLT processor you are using.

**Here is a small example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDeletePos" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <xsl:if test="not(position() = $pDeletePos)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, the global parameter named `pDeletePos` the position of the `num` element that must be deleted.

There is also a `default value` (3), specified for this parameter. This value will be used if the initiator of the transformation doesn't specify the `pDeletePos` parameter.

**When the above transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

and if the value of the `pDeletePos` is externally specified as `5`, then the transformation produces the following result:

```
<nums>
   <num>01</num>
   <num>02</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num>04</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num>07</num>
   <num>08</num>
   <num>09</num>
   <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

As for setting the parameter externally, here is how this is done in C#, when initiating the XslCompiledTransform XSLT processor:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx**

Comment: Good answer. It helped me with my problem of how to specify a parameter externally to an XSLT file.