# how to know input xml file with a given xslt

Tags: xslt

I have an defined xslt(in my old project) and I have an output file format genrated from this xslt , Now can we know the structure or input xml with these files?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on the input xml and your transformation neither of which you've shown

Comment: I cant paste the xslt file here

Comment: You can't paste - we can't tell. Sorry...

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly does  "*the structure or input xml*" mean?

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT 1.0:** Pass the filename in via a parameter.

**XSLT 2.0:** Use XPath 2.0 function `base-uri()`.

Comment: I am using xslt 1.0 , how to use the filename in via parameter

Comment: I do have an output final file too

Comment: Use a global `xsl:param`.   See [Input parameter in xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475131/input-parameter-in-xslt)

Comment: can you please give me specific ex for this reverse eng. small xslt , out put file and generate input file please

Comment: [**No.**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)   Read *[ask]*.