# Unable to use variable passed from C# into XSLT in a template match

Tags: c#, xslt

I'm trying to pass in a variable / parameter to an XSLT stylesheet. The variable is entered by the user via a Windows Form.

The XSLT stylesheet is quite simple and it processes lots of XML documents to filter out unwanted data, but leave specific data which has been selected by the user.

**The XSLT works perfectly well when I 'hard code' the variable into the template match** (i.e. not trying to programatically pass it in) so the parameter is clearly not being passed to the XSLT prior to transformation.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method = "xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements = "*" />

      <xsl:param name="applic"/>

        <xsl:template match = "@*|node()" >
          <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select = "@*|node()" />
         </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content//*[applic/model[@*]/version[@version != '$applic']]" />
        <xsl:template match = "version[@version != '$applic']" />

        <xsl:template match = "dmodule/content//applic" />

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how i'm passing the variable to the XSLT in C#

```
 XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
 args.AddParam("applic", "", applicToSearch); //applicToSearch contains the user variable

 var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
 myXslTrans.Load(stylesheet);

 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outputFolder, fileNameNoExt + ".xml")))
  {
       myXslTrans.Transform(outputFolder + "\\temp.xml", args, sw);
  }
```

As I say, clearly the variable / parameter isn't being passed successfully to the XSLT stylesheet.

Any idea why? I've exhausted Google and other posts.

Comment: Have you dropped a break point on the line with applicToSearch and verified it contains the value you expect when you run in Debug ?

Comment: Yep, and it certainly does when debugging. The value is there as expected.

Comment: `'$applic'` is the _string value_ `"$applic"`. It is not referencing the `$applic` variable. If you changed it to actually reference the variable (by removing the `''`), you would get an error telling you that you can't use variables in `match` expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm what Martin said - In XSLT 1.0 you can neither use a [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6117460/314291) nor a [param](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8839952/314291) in a template match.

By example, here's how you could replace a pair of parameterized templates with a template which provides branches for the desired parameter / variable values:

**Xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method = "xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements = "*" />

  <xsl:param name="applic" select="1"/>

  <xsl:template match = "@*|node()" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select = "@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match = "version">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@version=$applic">
        <Version match='true'/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <Version match='false'/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample Xml**

```
<xml>
  <version version='1'></version>
  <version version='2'></version>
</xml>
```

**Output**

```
<xml>
  <Version match="true" />
  <Version match="false" />
</xml>
```

**Edit, Re: But, I need to pass a parameter into the stylesheet?**

Any value embedded in the XSLT `param` value is simply a [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475389/314291) in the event that a value doesn't get passed in, i.e. `1` is just a default value - this makes it easier to test a new xslt under tools like Visual Studio.

```
  .... 1 is a default value here
  <xsl:param name="applic" select="1"/>
```

Your code for passing the parameter to the stylesheet works just fine as is, and will override the above default value:

```
var args = new XsltArgumentList();
args.AddParam("applic", "", "2"); // This value overrides anything defaulted in the xslt

myXslTrans.Transform("outfile.xml", args, streamWriter);
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, but is there no way of passing in the variable from my C# code to an xsl:if or xsl:choose/xsl:when? As opposed to explicitly stating it like you have in the example. Or at least that's what i think you've done (<xsl:param name="applic" select="1"/>). I'm new to XSLT.

Comment: That's just a default - any value passed in by code will override this value - I've updated.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use `@version != $applic` on the XSLT/XPath side. However, I think in XSLT 1 you can't use a variable in a `match` pattern so you would need to move such conditions into the template body with an `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose/xsl:when`.